# Blue Green deployment in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-replication

We have a SQL Server 2014 database and we are planning to do a blue green deployment to this database so that the downtime for this database can be reduced during the deployment window.

Are there any options that can be leveraged for implementing this solution?

Comment: Please describe how you want to sync data between blue and green? There is no easy way to do database schema changes.

Comment: @piotr - I am looking for data and schema syncing solutions for this. That was my question here

Comment: I'm not aware of any general solution, for example if a new release adds a new table and you get some data there, you can't just drop this table, so you can't rollback without data loss.

Comment: If you're trying to reduce downtime during a deployment, what operations are you performing that cause the downtime? A lot of things can be done in a way as to not affect database availability.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise following approach from [BlueGreenDeployment by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html):

> Databases can often be a challenge with this technique, particularly
> when you need to change the schema to support a new version of the
> software. The trick is to separate the deployment of schema changes
> from application upgrades. So first apply a database refactoring to
> change the schema to support both the new and old version of the
> application, deploy that, check everything is working fine so you have
> a rollback point, then deploy the new version of the application. (And
> when the upgrade has bedded down remove the database support for the
> old version.)